# Angular $scope module value lost on form submit

Tags: angularjs

I am instantiating an object that is used to store my form values:

```
$scope.placeSomething = {
    SomethingType: 1
};
```

And the form

```
<form name="placeSomething" id="placeSomething" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm();">
   ...form stuff...
</form>
```

if i check the existance of the default value of`$scope.placeSomething.SomethingType` inside my controller, it prints `1` - which is good.

But when i'm submitting the form, the default value is lost (unless i'm applying another value to `SomethingType` in some other function)

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {
    console.log($scope.placeSomething.SomethingType); // this returns undefined. the default values is lost
});
```

If i use ng-init inside the form, angular keeps the default value and sends it with the form.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="placeSomething.SomethingType" ng-init="placeSomething.SomethingType = 1"/>
```

why is this happening?

**Edit**

Another funny thing, is that if i change the $scope value from other $scope, it does not get lost on submit.

```
$scope.SelectSomethingType = function (param, SomethingType, param2) {
            $scope.placeSomething.SomethingType = SomethingType;
});
```

This function activated in one of the forms ng-clicks and saves the value to `SomethingType` just fine.

**Solved**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26905500/3628867 This was the problem

Comment: In case anyone experience the same behavior,
[this is][1] the answer. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26905500/3628867