# Why populating ng-model inside forms should be followed by $scope.$apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form:

```
<form name="placeThis" id="placeThis" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm();">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="placeThis.target"/>
</form>
```

And i want to add default value to `placeThis.target` from my controller, like this:

```
$scope.placeThis = { target: 0 }
```

But it isn't working if im not adding `$scope.$apply` or wrapping it inside `$timeout` (which will run `$scope.$apply` for me) .

I can save other $scope values from the controller without any problem, but values inside forms most be written inside `$timeout` or they get lost on submit. Why is this happening?

Comment: $scope.$apply should not be required. What is not working?

Comment: This is not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892978/angular-scope-module-value-lost-on-form-submit . I found a workaround i wanted to ask why it's even needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see demo below

You need to change name of your form from 'placeThis' to something else like 'placeThisForm'
otherwise you overwriting `$scope.placeThis` values set in your controller.

#### Please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.placeThis = {
    target: "One",
    name: "Tim"

  };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <form name="placeThisForm" id="placeThis" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm();">
      <label>Target</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="placeThis.target" />
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="placeThis.name" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the form name. You can read more about angular form here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form. It says:

> If the name attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name.

So, different object stored under this name in scope. Try to set different form name, like this:

```
<form name="placeThisForm" id="placeThis" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm();">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="placeThis.target"/>
</form>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.placeThis = { target: 0 }
```

Another way to set initial value is using *ng-init*

```
<form name="placeThisForm" id="placeThis" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm();">
   <input ng-init="placeThis.target = 0" type="input"  ng-model="placeThis.target"/>
</form>
```

Comment: +1 You are correct about my naming mistake, but this still didn't solved my problem