# Push form data to firebase not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-scope, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i am having problem with push data to firebase from angular. I am newbie in this so i need help to check what is wrong with my code

this is my code:
addrestaurant.html

```
<h4>Nama Restaurant</h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="namaResto" >
  <h4>Alamat:</h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="alamatResto">
  <h4>Image Link: </h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="imgResto">
  <h4> Category Restoran </h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="categoryResto">
  <h4>Price range:</h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="pricerangeResto">
  <h4>Location:</h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="locationResto">

  <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="sendRestaurant()">Send</button>
    </span>
```

main.js

```
/*global Firebase*/
'use strict';

angular.module('firebaseApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    var rootRef = new Firebase('https://yummy-364b1.firebaseio.com/');
    var childRest = rootRef.child('restaurant');
    var categoryRest =rootRef.child('category');

    $scope.namaResto = null;
    $scope.alamatResto = null;
    $scope.categoryResto =  null;
    $scope.imgResto = null;
    $scope.pricerangeResto = null;
    $scope.locationResto = null;



   childRest.on('value', function(snapshot){
      $timeout(function(){

        var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
        $scope.restaurant =snapshotVal;
      });
    });

 $scope.sendRestaurant = function() {


      childRest.push().set({
        nama: $scope.namaResto,
        alamat: $scope.alamatResto,
        category: $scope.categoryResto,
        img: $scope.imgResto,
        pricerange: $scope.pricerangeResto,
        locationarea: $scope.locationResto
      });
    };


 });
```

somehow when i remove push() and only using set() my existing data in firebase deleted. but if i using push() it doesn't change anything in firebase

sorry for my bad english. English isn't my primary language
thanks for help

**UPDATE** 
I already found my problem 
when i declare my variable in mainCtrl

```
$scope.namaResto = null;
 $scope.alamatResto = null;
 $scope.categoryResto =  null;
 $scope.imgResto = null;
 $scope.pricerangeResto = null;
 $scope.locationResto = null;
```

these things and values that send to firebase not from input form (addrestaurant.html) 
So now the problem is how that my controller can send value from my input form to firebase?

**SOLVED**
finally i found solution in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/26905500/3628867

Comment: I suggest you first add a completion callback to your push to check for any possible errors and add the outcome to your question. Like this:     childRest.push().set("I'm writing data", function(error) {
      if (error) {
        alert("Data could not be saved." + error);
      } else {
        alert("Data saved successfully.");
      }
    });

Comment: i tired your solution it works when i'm push string but when i change it into variable $scope.name it didn't works but the dialog box says data saved successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.sendRestaurant = function() {
 childRest.push({
    nama: $scope.namaResto,
    alamat: $scope.alamatResto,
    category: $scope.categoryResto,
    img: $scope.imgResto,
    pricerange: $scope.pricerangeResto,
    locationarea: $scope.locationResto
  });
};
```

source: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html

Comment: already tried that, Still not working nothing happenned in firebase

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with changing name of my $scope in ng-model form
from $scope.namaResto ={nama:null}; in controller
and in html form ng-model= "namaResto.nama"

for more detail see this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26905500/3628867